# Issue of reading input from fscanf

Tags: c++, user-input, eof, scanf

I'm trying to do a DFS search on a given graph using the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <vector>
    #include <queue>

    typedef struct G{
      int vertex1;
      int vertex2;
      float num;
    } graph;

    typedef struct adj{
      std::vector<int> element;
    }adj;

    void dfs (int v, bool marked[], adj*p){
       marked[v]=true;
       std::vector<int>::iterator i;
       for (i=p[v].element.begin(); i!=p[v].element.end();i++){
            if (!marked[*i]){
            dfs(*i, marked, p);
            }
        }
    }

    void Search(adj*p, int*tvertex){
       bool *marked=new bool[*tvertex];
       for (int v=0; v<*tvertex; v++){
           marked[v]=false;
           }
       for (int v=0; v<*tvertex;v++){
          if (marked[v]==false){
             dfs(v, marked,p);
            }
        }
     }

    void buildadj(graph*g, adj*p, int * tvertex, int *edge ){
       for (int e=0; e<*edge; e++){ 
           p[g[e].vertex1].element.push_back(g[e].vertex2);
           p[g[e].vertex2].element.push_back(g[e].vertex1);
        }
    }

    void readInData(FILE *fp, graph*g, int *tvertex) {
         char buffer[500];
         char *token;
         const char delimiters[] = " ";
         int i;
         int n;
         memset(buffer, 0, 499);
         for(i = 0;!feof(fp);) {
            i++;
            if (i>=2){
               fscanf(fp, " %[^\n]", buffer);
               token = strtok(buffer, delimiters);
               n = (int) atoi(token); 
               g[i-2].vertex1 = n;
               g[i-2].vertex2 =  (int) atoi(strtok(NULL, delimiters));
               g[i-2].num = (float)atof(strtok(NULL, delimiters));
            }
          }
     }
    void readstrct(FILE *fp,int*edge, int*tvertex){
         int i;
         int a[2];
         while (EOF!=fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &a[i])) {
               i++;     
              if(i>=2){
                 break;
                }
          }
         *tvertex=a[0];
         *edge=a[1];
    }

    void sendMessage() {
        char message[200];
        sprintf(message, "Wrong Format\n");
        printf("%s", message);
    }
   int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        FILE *fp;
        int edge;
        int tvertex;
        if(argc < 2) {
           printf("File not given\n");
           sendMessage();
           return 0;
          }
        fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(fp == NULL) {
           printf("file not found\n");
           sendMessage();
           return 0;
         }
        readstrct(fp,&edge, &tvertex);
        graph *g=new graph[edge];
        adj *p=new adj[tvertex];
        readInData(fp, g, &tvertex);
        buildadj(g,p,&tvertex, &edge);
        Search(p,&tvertex);
   }
```

The input is of the following form:

1. 13
2. 13
3. 0 5 2.1
4. 4 3 2.3
5. 0 1 3.2
6. 9 12 4.2
7. 6 4 5.1
8. 5 4 2.2
9. 0 2 0.2
10. 11 12 0.22
11. 9 10 0.22
12. 0 6 0.22
13. 7 8 0.22
14. 9 11 0.22
15. 5 3 0.22

Please focus on the readstruct and readIndata function where the data is read

and stored. I intend to read the first two lines (13 and 13) and stores these

two values as  edges and vertex num in the '***readstruct***' function.

After reading line 1 and line 2, the if condition is satisfied and goes out

of loop.

Line 3 and Line 15 are read in the ***readIndata*** when i larger than 1

Since per-line contains three data and space between them, I used char array

to store them and read one character by one character. The Segmention faul

error shows when the code continues to read the file when it reaches line

15(or i=13) in  ***readIndata*** function, where it should stop. So I guess

something messed up with filepointer or fscanf function.

Best

Comment: Don't mix C and C++ like that.

Comment: Ok, but I'm wondering whether this is the cause of problem

Comment: Always check return value of `fscanf` so that you catch both EOF *and* parse errors (like trying to read a number when there is text).

Comment: Also, please indent your code properly. Trying to figure out what's wrong with badly indented code is basically making the problem intentionally harder to solve.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. I am very confused myself, because the error totally does not makes sense. I re-edited the post. Hopefully, it makes more sense now.

Comment: What you need to edit is the source code. I'm not going to spend my time trying to parse unformatted source code if you're not going to take the time to format it.

Comment: I reformatted the code. I hope it is now easy to read by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You must first initialize `i` in `readstrct()`.  As the post reads now, it is used as an index into the integer array, `a`.

Comment: @Sean, please update the code in your post to reflect that, as well as any other updates you've made.  When that shows the latest you've tested, and still gotten the error, I will be glad to look again.